# Font-awsome 5 house icon won't show when using fa-solid fa-house

Tags: css, font-awesome

I can't seem to get the font awesome icons to show.

I've imported font-awesome 5 and tried to use the following icon https://fontawesome.com/icons/house?f=classic&s=solid

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Font Awesome Example</title>
    <!-- Add Font Awesome CSS link here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-gOXQS8AR6DaIm7mMSpgqQ8MEcsp5DcTj8+9y+pKlc3VsLe9QlTuC4cBu/QbUlgeLY5FcfFv7p9AJRAj/EbNqA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />-->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Font Awesome Example</h1>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>       
</body>
</html>
```

Solved: by using the font-awesome 6 cdn :(!!

Answer (score 0):

Did this instead and the fa-solid fa-house icon works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Font Awesome Example</title>
  <!-- Add Font Awesome CSS link here -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Font Awesome Example</h1>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>       
</body>
</html>
```